# udev shell script read conf-file from usb

Tags: linux, bash, shell, server, udev

i wrote an udev rule that executes an shell script when a usb-drive is plugged in. After that i mount this device and want to read a config file from this stick into my running shell script, that was started by the udev rule. 
The whole thing should sync my project files with the files on the usb-device. Therefore i'd like to have an .conf file to say especially which files i want to sync., turn on logging this whole routine, say in which side it should sync. (usb->pc or pc->usb).

So here we go. This is the code-snippet which should read the conf-file.

```
#####################################
#   TODO:
#       sync.-config file
#####################################
sleep 1         # wait till device is mounted

if [ -f $config ]   # check if a config file exist
then
    echo "reading config file..." >> $log
    . $config   # read config file
    echo "$incremental" >> $logf
    echo "$log" >> $logf
    echo "$unmount" >> $logf
    echo "$exec" >> $logf
fi
```

but this won't work as expected, and i have no idea why O_o
The conf-file looks like this:

```
incremental="1"         # choose sync.: incremental = 1, full = 0
log="1"                 # enable log = 1, disable = 0
unmount="1"             # enable unmount after sync. = 1, disable = 0 
exec=""                 # shell script which will be executed 
                        # before the sync. (install packages etc.)
```

I tried this in an script which was not started by a udev rule and it works... 
What can i do or can i do something to get this stuff work ?

ps.: $config is the path to the conf file... :)

Comment: Which distribution are you using? Do you want to run it for all flash drives or just for specific one?

Comment: i am running Ubuntu 14.04 Server.
And yes, it should work with every flash device. But this isn't the problem. Every device will be mounted and checked, if a specific file is on the drive. If this true, the whole process will start otherwise it will be unmounted and the routine ends.

Comment: So your problem is with udev only? Could you post the udev rule you are using and any other related script.